# Returning user to the same page through login and register forms using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a sign in and register form, that both work.  They are on the same page,

login form uses:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login')) }}
```

and registering uses:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'register')) }}
```

These are then directed to different functions in the HomeController, after success they return the member view.

My issue is that instead of directing the user to url.com/member, I get url.com/login for login and url.com/register for register as the url for the member view.

Is there a correct way of doing this? I've been looking through the documentation and I've come across

```
Redirect::url('member')
```

as an option, but if I do it for both register and login functions, I get a http routing error exception, that doesn't allow me to do it.

If anyone could help me, that would be great.

In addition, here are my functions for registering and logging in:

login:

```
    public function doLogin()
{
    // validate the info, create rules for the inputs
    $rules = array(
        'email'    => 'required|email', // make sure the email is an actual email
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3' // password can only be alphanumeric and has to be greater than 3 characters
    );

    // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/')
            ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
            ->withInput(Input::except('password')); // send back the input (not the password) so that we can repopulate the form
    } else {

        // create our user data for the authentication
        $userdata = array(
            'email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
        );

        // attempt to do the login
        if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

            // validation successful!
            // redirect them to the secure section or whatever
            // return Redirect::to('secure');
            return View::make('member');

        } else {        

            // validation not successful, send back to form 
            return Redirect::to('/');

        }

    }
}
```

Register:

HomeController function:

```
    public function doRegister()
{


    $name = Input::get('name');
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $password = Input::get('password');

    $userData = array(
        array('name' => $name),
        array('email' => $email),
        array('password' => $password),
    );
    User::addNewUser($name, $email, $password);
    return View::make('member');

}
```

User Model:

```
    public static function addNewUser($name, $email, $password)
{

    DB::table('users')->insert(array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'password' => Hash::make($password)));
}
```

routes:

```
// route to show the login form
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@showHome'));
//Route::get('/register', array('uses' => 'HomeController@showRegister'));

// route to process the form
Route::post('login', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doLogin'));


Route::post('register', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doRegister'));
```

Comment: Could you add your related `routes.php` content?

Comment: @ManuelPedrera I've added the routes now, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this:

`return Redirect::to('member')`

You need to have that route defined in your `routes.php`, like so:

```
// routes.php
...

Route::get('member', function()
{
    return View::make('member');
});

...
```

Now that you have it defined, you can use this in your `doLogin` and `doRegister` actions:

```
// HomeController.php
...

if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
    return Redirect::to('member');
}

...
```

Also, notice that instead of hardcoding a redirect to `'/'` when validaton fails, you can return `Redirect::back()`.